Ordering columns In a Power BI matrix by column not in matrix
I have a matrix in power bi that needs to calculate each event as a percentage of the opening event this is being done by the measures
    OpeningEventIDs = CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[UserCount]), Sheet1[StepName] = "Opening Event")

    %OfOpeningEvent = DIVIDE(SUM(Sheet1[UserCount]), [OpeningEventIDs])

The values need to also be dynamic to the slicer "Colour name" so to recalculate the "Opening Event" each time
I am then trying to reorder the columns so that Opening Event is first, they have been assigned a number each and i am doing this by the "Sort by column" feature, this then breaks the table, i have included two images the first has the correct values but wrong column order, the second is after sorting by column, the correct outcome should be the same values but with opening event as the first column
Correct Values, Wrong Order
Wrong Values, Correct Order
data

you can create a new table which includes step name and sort column

then create the relationship between your data table and this new table
then sort the step name column by sort column

in the matrix visual, drag the step name from the new table to the column field, then you will get the correct order.

